How do I exactly use CloudFront to download Images?
I have a 1 on 1 chat app wherein users can share image/videos files with each other. My auth uses Cognito, media files are stored in S3, APIs are using Lambda and API Gateway.
For messages that contains an image, I store the image's id on DynamoDB (e.g. imageId: 1234-5678-1234.jpg).
The way I upload images is: lambda generates an S3 presigned URL -> client uploads an image thru that URL -> do these steps for every uploads
As for media downloads, how do I do it? I want to use CloudFront. My idea is this, but I need confirmation whether I'm pursuing the right thing: lambda generates a CloudFront presigned URL that expires every n mins -> client can fetch any of their photos using that presigned URL.
But what if I want to fetch multiple files (images/videos) at a single time using the single presigned URL?

Fetching multiple files using a single presigned URL is not directly feasible because each presigned URL corresponds to a specific resource (object) or path in S3 or CloudFront. This means that if a client needs to download multiple files, individual URLs would typically need to be generated for each file. While functional, this approach can become inefficient and cumbersome for bulk downloads.
One secure solution is to use a Lambda function to handle batch downloads dynamically. When a client requests multiple files by providing their imageIds, the Lambda function can retrieve the files from S3, compress them into a ZIP archive, upload the ZIP to a temporary S3 bucket, and generate a presigned URL for it. The client can then use this single presigned URL to download all the requested files as a ZIP. Temporary storage and lifecycle policies ensure that the ZIP files are automatically deleted after a short duration, optimizing costs.
Alternatively, if your files follow a common path structure (e.g., /user/{userId}/files/), you could configure CloudFront to allow path-based presigned URLs. This method enables users to access all files under that path with one URL. However, this approach lacks granularity, as it would expose all files within the path, even if the client only requested specific ones. Thus, while simpler, this method sacrifices some control over file-level access.
Extending your lambda function to allow zipping multiple files is better if you want to keep control on your security.
